# Windows 10 slow wake up (more than 1 minute)

Tags: windows-10, sleep, wake-up, powersave

After recent update, my Windows 10 box started to wake up very slowly. After I touched keyboard, display wakes up, I see background with greeting, I see mouse moves, I see clock minutes icreasing, but login cell to enter password doesn't appear for more than 1 minute.

What is happening here and how to fix? Is it new power safe mode or something?

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎13.‎07.‎2022
OS build    19044.1826
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
```

Comment: Use the manufacturer's Driver Update App and update drivers - particularly power driver and BIOS (UEFI).

Answer (score 0):

It was because in this new version of Windows they changed keystroke for password prompt from any key to Ctrl-Alt-Del.